# Javascript datetime format validation regex [dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex for datetime validation in dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm format.

### What I Tried

```
/^(([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])[\/\-\.]([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/\-\.][1-2]\d{3}) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1})$/
```

But its not working. I am getting invalid format.

Comment: (I recommend using moment.js as it can also say if it's a *valid* date: e.g. not a leap year. Plus, someone *else* wrote and tested the parser..)

Comment: Sorry, not helping on the original post, but have a peek at http://momentjs.com/. Will make your JS date woes disappear.

Comment: Make sure not to use the .isValid() function of Momentjs version 2.12.0 - it has a bug when validating "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, a regex is a poor way to check that you have a valid date.

If you do want a regex, this fits your format:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](19|20)[0-9]{2} (2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]
```

And it will reject most invalid dates and times... but it will accept dates such as 29-02-2013.

Whatever the language, you are much better off trying to make a date with the input string—if it fails, you don't have a valid date.

By the way the brackets in `[-]` are not needed, but for such a regex it's not a bad idea to put the hyphen in a char class in case one later wants to add other separators. Your initial regex suggests that you may have wanted to do this.